# Egit pull and merge changes

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I was working locally on master branch. (by mistake) but it's ok with me this time as I control my code.

I took the following steps:

1. Egit->commit and push (to master)
2. Egit -> pull (to get other developers changes)
3. I got a message that there is a conflict with one file and I merged it.
4. Now I see: [My Product | Merged Master (up arrow)2 (down arrow)1]
5. I see in the symbols next to the files that the other developers created - black sign as if there are uncommitted.

A. What does the 2 up arrow and 1 down arrow mean?

B. Why do I see uncommitted changes? they are not mine

C. How can I work out on master after my merge?

D. I looked in bitbucket and didn't see that my changes were committed to the remote branch. What is wrong?

I know that I am supposed to work on branches - but for now - how do I fix the situation?

Comment: on step #3. You saw that there was a conflict and then merged it? When there is a conflict, you have to resolve it and then do a ``merge commit``. You may want to double check that file again...

Comment: I saw that there was a conflict in .classpath file that shouldn't be in GIT. so I marked it as ignore.

Comment: double check that .classpath file. You probably have git conflict markers in there. That could mess you up. Also, add any files to be ignored to your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Two arrows up means you have two commits in your local branch that aren't in the remove branch. The one arrow down means there is one commit in the remote branch that you don't have locally. The solution is to do a `git pull` followed by a `git push`

B. Uncommitted changes are probably from your conflict. After a conflict, you have to resolve the conflict, add it to index and then commit that change. This is known as a `merge commit`. My guess is you have not done this.

C. Work out on master? You mean you want to work directly on top of master? After you resolve your conflict, you should be all set to do that. Branching is better though. To create your own branch just do `git checkout -b my_featue_branch`

Comment: Thanks. What about D? why I don't see my committed changes?

Comment: You probably haven't pushed. Basically what happened was you tried to push, your remote repo said, not so fast, you need to pull first to get the latest from me. At that point you saw a conflict. So, I think you need to first resolve and commit your conflict (make sure you have nothing in index or modified files in the working directory). Then you need to do a ``git pull`` followed by a ``git push``